# About race condtiion

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, mutual-exclusion

When I complie this code I can get a result like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnnrX.png)

The code is like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sched.h>

void *thread_entry(void *ptr)
      {
int i, j, len;
char *str = (char *) ptr;

len = strlen(str);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)   
 {
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    putchar(str[j]);
    sched_yield(); /*to yield CPU*/
                           }
    putchar('\n');
 }
      }

int main()
 {
pthread_t thread1, thread2;
const char *msg1 = "Hello This is Thread 1.";
const char *msg2 = "I am Thread 2.";

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_entry, (void *) msg1);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread_entry, (void *) msg2);

pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

return 0;
 }
```

That is code. I think because of Common Resource but I am not sure. Please teach me why the result is like this. I really appereciate it!

Comment: You said it already. There is race condition here. You should use `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` around the critical section.

Comment: @John Is No Thank you for saying so !!

Comment: This code is deliberately designed to highlight the use of the output stream by more than one thread.  It's obviously an academic exercise.  Please see your prof/tutor for additional direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely as you think.
The output is a shared resource and the two threads are simultaneously trying to push characters to it.
Indeed you've put a yield in that will encourage (but not control) flipping in and out of the threads.

You've done nothing to control the interleaving of the two threads and you inevitably get the garbled output shown in the screen shot.

Without knowing what you're trying to do there isn't a lot more to say.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it.... But I wonder how do I have to stduy??

Comment: You need a pthreads tutorial. It's a bigger subject with some broad foundation principles that you won't easily get by asking questions on Stackoverflow. I don't know a good tutorial on pthreads.
Your easiest change is (as advised by John is No) locking and unlocking a shared mutex to ensure each string is output in full. The will (probably) lead to output like ABABABBAAABBABABAB  where the two threads mostly flip flop but occasionally one has two or more runs before going back. 
A more interesting exercise is to ensure you get ABABABA output with strict alternation.